# htc one message notification problem

Tags: htc

Yesterday I bought the HTC One which was a huge step up from the iPhone 4s which I had owned. I have one problem with the phone: I cant find a way to view a contacts notification for a text without it displaying the message in the form of a preview. Is there any way I can change the settings so that the ls will show the sender but not the message preview. Im looking for something similar to ios where it would display the contacts name and it would say "text message"

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot disable text preview completely. You can adjust how many lines you'd like to see (1-3), but like iOS native Messages.app you will be presented with a message preview.

That being said, on Android platform you can replace most default applications with the ones you like more. Perhaps you will be able to find SMS/MMS app that offers this sort of customizability.